# Javascript two different counters

Tags: javascript

I have this problem and somehow i cannot resolve it. I need my function to print counter1 (1, 2, 3) and then I need my counter2 to count from zero, not continuing the counter1. (counter1 and counter2 incrementing asynchronously)
I need to print count as following: 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3.

```
  function ukol2() {
      var count = 0;
      function makeCounter() {
        return function() {
          count++;
          console.log(count);
        };
      }

      var counter1 = makeCounter();
      counter1(); //1
      counter1(); //2
      counter1(); //3

      var counter2 = makeCounter();
      counter2(); //4
      counter2(); //5
      counter2(); //6
    }
```

Comment: declare count variable right after your function makeCounter.

Comment: put the `var count = 0` inside the `makeCounter` so that they each have independent variable?

Comment: _counter1 and counter2 incrementing asynchronously_ there's nothing asynchronous here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `count` variable is global, put it inside your function `makeCounter`.

```js
function ukol2() {
  function makeCounter() {
    let count = 0;
    return function() {
      count++;
      console.log(count);
    };
  }

  var counter1 = makeCounter();
  counter1(); //1
  counter1(); //2
  counter1(); //3

  var counter2 = makeCounter();
  counter2(); //4
  counter2(); //5
  counter2(); //6
}

ukol2();
```

See? Now your counter increments independently.

**UPDATE**: As recommendation from [@DiamondDrake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822223/diamonddrake):

Change this `var count = 0;` to `let count = 0;` for scoping

## Resource

> [`Let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)
>
> The let statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

Comment: Thanks mate, ure genius, if i have my reputation higher, i would give you 100 ups.

Comment: I would recommend changing `var count = 0;` to `let count = 0;` for scoping.

Comment: @DiamondDrake agree!